# setGravity en un Toast no me funciona

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-toast

estoy empezando a programar en Kotlin y tengo un problema a la hora de realizar un setGravity para un Toast.

Lo ponga como lo ponga, me aparece en la posición por defecto.

He probado estas dos opciones:

```
var toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Seleccione una respuesta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
toast.show() 


Toast.makeText(this, "Seleccione una respuesta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).apply {setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0); show() }
```

La idea sería que el toast apareciese al principio de la pantalla en lugar de abajo del todo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente el problema esté en el layout. Cualquiera de las opciones que probaste debería haber funcionado.

Prueba esto

```
        Snackbar
            .make(container, "Seleccione una respuesta", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .apply {
                (view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.TOP
            }
            .show()
```

Aunque la verdadera pregunta sería por qué quieres que aparezca arriba?

Según la [guia de estilos de material design](https://material.io/components/snackbars#placement):

> At the bottom of the UI
>
> Snackbars should be placed at the
> bottom of a UI, in front of app content. Avoid placing a snackbar in
> front of frequently used touch targets or navigation.